# Accessing Twitter API from Parse

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform

can i use Parse to access the Twitter REST API? i want to be able to query tweets through keywords/hastags. Twitter isn't that clear in their developer website, like there is no tutorials or a map on how to move through learning their API like Parse is doing.

Comment: Parse is a backend service for storing your app's data. How are you thinking of coupling this with the Twitter API?

Comment: umm.. since it facilitate the log in/out of facebook and twitter,  was wandering if they actually offer such kind of service to access or query tweets (for example) from twitter in a simple way other than using SLRequest.